# doxygen @param confused by @file tag

Tags: doxygen

All,

I am trying to get a handle on doxygen tags, and have encountered the following 'issue'.
In the code shown below, if I remove the @file doxytest.c from the second line, all is well.  If, however, I leave it in, the output log contains this:

/Users/bp/learn/gendoxy/gendoxy/doxytest.c:10: warning: argument 'int' of command @param is not found in the argument list of foobar0(int folder)
/Users/bp/learn/gendoxy/gendoxy/doxytest.c:10: warning: The following parameters of foobar0(int folder) are not documented:
  parameter 'folder'

This makes no sense to me (should it?)  This is in a '.c' file, running on a MacOS.
What am I doing wrong? -- I would like to have the @file tag, and no warnings/errors from doxygen.

Or, gasp!, is this a bug?

```
/*!
 *  @file doxytest.c
 *
 *  @author bp 
 *  @version 0.0.1
 *  @copyright (2013) we be nerds,LLC 
 */

 /*!  
  *   @brief  void foobar0 ( int folder )
  *     does little to better the world.
  *
  *   @param [in] int folder :- one small step
  *
  */

  void foobar0 ( int folder )
  {
    for (int ii = 0; ii < folder; ii++)
    {
        foobar1( ii );
    }
}


/*!
 * @brief foobar2  ( int x )
 * does half of what foobar1 does.
 *
 */

void foobar1( int x )
{
    return( x /2 );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not include the variable type in the doxygen comment

```
  *   @param [in] folder :- one small step
```

Otherwise it thinks your documenting the variable 'int', and it also thinks you forgot to document the variable 'folder'.

So yes, you should keep the @file tag.  Honestly I find it strange that removing the @file tag made the warning go away.